# Java swing problems with prepareRenderer

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm implementing the interface of a game in swing. This game has a board which is represented by a jtable.

Each cell have a number between 0 and 6.

I would like to make the table show colored "O" instead of numbers, like this:
1 - > green
2 - > red
etc...
I have implemented this:

```
public class DTable extends JTable{
@Override
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int rowIndex, int columnIndex){
    Component component = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, rowIndex, columnIndex);
    component.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    component.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    if ((getValueAt(rowIndex, columnIndex) != null)){

        String val = (String) getValueAt(rowIndex, columnIndex);
        setValueAt("O", rowIndex, columnIndex);
        System.out.println("el valor de val es "+val);

        if ("0".equals(val)){
            Color col = new Color(255,255,255);
            component.setForeground(col);
        }
        else if ("1".equals(val)){
            Color col = new Color(255,114,145);
            component.setForeground(col);
        }
        else if ("2".equals(val)){
            Color col = new Color(255,0,0);
            component.setForeground(col);

        }
        else if ("3".equals(val)){
            Color col = new Color(52,146,153);
            component.setForeground(col);

        }
        else if ("4".equals(val)){
            Color col = new Color(0,3,204);
            component.setForeground(col);

        }
        else if ("5".equals(val)){
            Color col = new Color(191,206,20);
            component.setForeground(col);

        }
        else if ("6".equals(val)){
            Color col = new Color(20,206,98);
            component.setForeground(col);

        }
        System.out.println("que pasa aqui");

    }

    return component;
}
```

The problem is that it puts all black "O" to the cells. 
If I try to show to value of "val", the first line gives me a number between 0 and 6 but then it shows me a "O" always.

I believe the problem here is that I don't use the prepareRenderer correctly, but I'm not really sure.
Also, I'm open to suggestions about how to change numbers on a cell to colored "O" if you think I shouldn't be using this method.
Thanks!

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setValueAt("O", rowIndex, columnIndex);
```

The problem is that you change the data in the TableModel. When the data is changed the table needs to repaint itself so your prepearRenderer(...) method gets invoked a second time and this time the value of the cell is "0".

Don't change the data in the model. Get rid of that statement.

Instead you can change the data in the renderer. The default renderer is a JLabel so you can do something like:

```
//Component component = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, rowIndex, columnIndex);
JLabel renderer = (JLabel)super.prepareRenderer(renderer, rowIndex, columnIndex);
renderer.setText("0");
```